# How to Merge inner array elements in php using array functions?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this.

```
array (size=4)
 0 => 
array (size=1)
  'serial_id' => string '214' (length=3)
 1 => 
array (size=1)
  'serial_id' => string '218' (length=3)
 2 => 
array (size=1)
  'serial_id' => string '221' (length=3)
 3 => 
array (size=1)
  'serial_id' => string '319' (length=3)
```

and i want this as single array

```
  array (size=4)
'0' => string '214' (length=3)
'1' => string '218' (length=3)
'2' => string '221' (length=3)
'3' => string '319' (length=3)
```

I don't want to run loop, is there any array function which gives my required output

Can anyone help me out??? 
I am new to array functions of php.
Thanks for all answers, but waiting for Shortest answer using array functions.. 
This is my code in php

```
    <?php 
    $array = array( array('serial_id' => 214),
         array('serial_id' => 218 ),
         array('serial_id' => 221),
         array('serial_id' => 319) );
    var_dump($array);

    $array2 = array(218,214,221,319);
    var_dump($array2);
    ?>
```

Comment: loop through the array & rebuild it ? sounds easy. Show your PHP codes.

Comment: FYI: you cannot have duplicate keys, using `foreach` or `array_column` will work just fine.

Comment: It can be wrong..as key is same..not if key is same then it will get override with last value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code, I see that you are update your question

```
      <?php
    function convert_array($a) {
        for($j = 0; $j < count($a); $j++) {
            $b[$j] = $a[$j]['serial_id'];
        }
    return $b;
    }

   $array = array( array('serial_id' => 214),
         array('serial_id' => 218 ),
         array('serial_id' => 221),
         array('serial_id' => 319) );

    $array2 = convert_array($array);

        var_dump($array2);

        ?>
```

If you use php > 5.5.0

```
   <?php

   $array = array( array('serial_id' => 214),
         array('serial_id' => 218 ),
         array('serial_id' => 221),
         array('serial_id' => 319) );

$array2 = array_column($array, 'serial_id');

    var_dump($array2);

    ?>
```

Comment: Not yet... waiting for array function which does this same functionality.

Comment: Your Answer is correct. Is there any possibility in predefined array functions like array_chunk in php to do this???. I tried this code., It worked but I want to use php predefined functions for this purpose.

Comment: Yup,this is what I want. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this..this is your old array..try to arrange it..consider it as example..

```
 $array = array(0 => array("serial_id"=>"214"),  
              1 => array("serial_id"=>"218"), 
              2 => array("serial_id"=>"221"),
              3 => array("serial_id"=>"319")
              );
```

You can use foreach to get inner element in one new array
    $new_array = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$inner_array){

```
   foreach($inner_array as $k=>$v){
    $new_array[$k] = $v;
   }
}



  Output will be
$new_array = array(
    'serial_id_1' => string '214',
    'serial_id_2' => string '218',
    'serial_id_3' => string '221',
    'serial_id_4' => string '319',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array as in the below example to produce your new array:

```
$array = array("0" => array("serial_id"=>"214"),  
              "1" => array("serial_id"=>"218"), 
              "2" => array("serial_id"=>"221"),
              "3" => array("serial_id"=>"319")
              );
$new_arr=array();              
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
$new_arr["serial_id_".$key]=$value["serial_id"];
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

Try it out here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2291c9eaf9842fdbeda4fd69bc707d7404b390d0

Loop-through new array

```
foreach( $new_arr as $key => $value ){
    echo $key."\t=>\t".$value."\n";
}
```